# Date() .setDate() inconsistent behaviour

Tags: javascript, date

According to

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate

I should expect that setDate() in code

```
var now = new Date();
now.setDate(0);
```

will change *now* to the last day of the previous month.

It means I should be able to do something like this:

```
now.setDate(0).setDate(1)
```

to get the date of the first day of the previous month.

But id doesn't work like that.

```
var now = new Date();
console.log(now)
// FF 24: Date {Wed Jul 09 2014 16:35:49 GMT+0100 (IST)}

now.setDate(0);
console.log(now)
// FF 24: Date {Mon Jun 30 2014 16:35:49 GMT+0100 (IST)}
```

But

```
var now = new Date().setDate(0);
console.log(now)
// 1404142784241
```

**Question:**

What is difference between

```
var now = new Date();
now.setDate(0);
```

and

```
var now = new Date().setDate(0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second example, you're looking at the **return value** of the `.setDate()` function, and not the date itself. The `.setDate()` function returns the timestamp value corresponding to the updated value of the object.  It's like doing this:

```
var now = new Date();
now.setDate(0);
console.log(now.getTime());
```

Comment: I have read the definition of the setDate() function in the ECMA specification, and that's right, the function returns the timestamp. It however breaks the functional approach :( BUT there is a great library http://momentjs.com/ which provides you with the actual object and methods ready to chain.